# The dmaengine in Linux - how to check the number of actually transferred bytes in a single SG transfer?

Tags: linux, drivers, dma

The [dmaengine](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/Documentation/dmaengine/client.txt) in Linux significantly simplifies writing of drivers for devices using DMA, especially if they support and use scatter-gather (SG) transfers.

However, there is a problem in case if the length of such transfer is not known a priori. This situation is quite common. It may happen in case of USB transfers, or in case of AXI Stream transfers. In the case of an AXI Stream connected device, the transfer should be terminated by setting the tlast signal to '1'. The driver should prepare the buffer for the longest possible transfer, but after the transfer is complete, it should be able to find the number of actually transferred bytes. Unfortunately it seems, that there is no documented way to read the length of the completed transfer.

The single transfer is represented with an [SG-table](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/scatterlist.h#L38), that is later converted into the [dma_async_tx_descriptor](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/dmaengine.h#L471), using the [dmaengine_prep_slave_sg](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/dmaengine.h#L774) function , submitted to the DMA layer (e.g. like [here](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/drivers/net/ethernet/micrel/ks8842.c#L468)), and finally scheduled for execution via [dma_async_issue_pending](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/dmaengine.h#L1074). After that, the transfer descriptor may be accessed only via a dma_cookie returned by the dmaengine_prep_slave_sg function.

The problem with determining the actual length of the transfer was reported for the USB transfers, and a [patch](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg89942.html) adding the `transferred` field to the dma_async_tx_descriptor was proposed. However that proposal was rejected, and after a discussion a [solution](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg90398.html) based on using the [dmaengine_tx_status](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/dmaengine.h#L855), and checking the `residue` field in the returned  [dma_tx_state](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/#linux+v4.4/include/linux/dmaengine.h#L589) structure.

Unfortunately, it seems that the proposed solution does not work neither in the 4.4 kernel (used for Xilinx SoC devices) nor in the newest 4.7 kernel.
The `residue` field is [set to 0](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/xilinx-v2016.2/drivers/dma/xilinx/xilinx_dma.c#L561) in case of completed transfers regardless of the actual number of transferred bytes.

**So my question is: How can I reliably determine the actual number of transferred bytes in the completed SG DMA transfer in a dmaengine compatible driver?**

PS. That question with more Xilinx-specific details related to the AXI DMA IP core [has been also asked](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/AXI-DMA-checking-the-number-of-really-transferred-bytes-for/td-p/715636) on the Xilinx forum.